# How to read large text files on Android?

Tags: android, file, firebase, io

How do I read large text files as GTFS files ([Google Transit](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/?hl=pt-br)) and put these on Firebase database? The problem is that I've used various forms and all my application returns the error OutOfMemory!

Comment: Are you trying to read all of data to RAM at a time?

Comment: I did not really your question, but I read in a AsyncTask all data , I have also tried to separate

Comment: How big is the file?  > 2MB?

Comment: a file contains 83 MB @Veener

Answer (score 0):

Cutting the file into several pieces may help.

Comment: There is a Programmatic way to do this ??

Answer (score 0):

With large file, use buffer to read it. Else when you read, data cached all in memory (RAM) and this is cause to exception outofmemory.